# How can I get the date of the created field(django model field) in the format I want?

Tags: python, django

current is this

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
July 13, 2020, 8:06 a.m.
```

and I want to change date format

```
July 13, 2020, 8:06 a.m. => 20year 6month 13day
```

is this possible?

if you know how to change thanks for let me know !

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a format: [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield)

Format localization: [Format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/formatting/)